# gSoap specify Input parameter With class Compound Data Type

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

i'm trying to create a method that has a class as one of his parameters. when I send from the client to the server i found that the object send is always empty
this is my .h file that i used to generate the server and the client

```
class FamilleProduit
{
private:
    int Id;
    std::string Libelle;
public:
    FamilleProduit();
    ~FamilleProduit();
    int getId();
    void setId(int value);
    std::string getLibelle();
    void setLibelle(std::string value);
};


int ns__ajouterByType ( FamilleProduit familleproduit, bool* result);
int ns__ajouterByLibelle ( std::string libelle, bool* result);
```

and this is the client

```
.......
struct soap m;
FamilleProduit f;
f.setLibelle("byTypeLocal");
soap_init(&m);
soap_call_ns__ajouterByType(&m,server,"",f,&res);
.........
```

this is the server part

```
int ns__ajouterByType(struct soap* soap, FamilleProduit f, bool *result){
    cout<<"Ajout FamilleProduit "<<f.getLibelle()<<endl;

    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

I found that always the object FamilleProduit is empty

> For information i'm using the same code to send a string and i have no
>   problem.

plz help and thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in the declaration of `class FamilleProduit` I must put the attribute public. I don't know why! but it works.
The new .h file

```
// Content of file "Test.h": 
//gsoap ns service name: Test 
//gsoap ns service protocol: SOAP 
//gsoap ns service style: rpc 
//gsoap ns service encoding: encoded 
//gsoap ns schema namespace: urn:MutexColisage

class ns1__FamilleProduit
{
    int Id;
    std::string Libelle;
    ns1__FamilleProduit();
    ~ns1__FamilleProduit();
    int getId();
    void setId(int value);
    std::string getLibelle();
    void setLibelle(std::string value);
};


int ns__ajouterByType ( ns1__FamilleProduit *familleproduit, bool* result);
int ns__ajouterByLibelle ( std::string libelle, bool* result);
```